# How to get TTL of a received UDP datagram using Winsock?

Tags: udp, winsock, ttl

is it possible to get the IP field TTL (time to live) of a received UDP datagram on Windows using Winsock? Or is the only way to get this value using WinPcap with an appropriate filter to capture all incoming UDP datagrams for a given socket??? But to be honest, I don't like this solution... is there a better way?

Thanks